# How to save variable using await function and use callback when error occurs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request, async-await

well I'm immigrating my code to ES7, syntaxes like arrow function and async/await. The problem is I don't get how to use call back when If I try to save variable and callback when error occurs at the same time using `async/await`.

Here's the code. I want to save result from request to redditJSON variable using await with rp but I want to add callback for error handling too. but I have no idea how to implement this.

*`rp` is request-promise npm module.*

```
let redditJSON = await rp(optForReddit)
```

**EDIT 1**

```
let redditJSON;
try { redditJSON = await rp(optForReddit) }
catch(err) { console.error(err) }
```

Comment: How about using `try...catch`?

Comment: @elclanrs oh that'd be a way. but I wonder If I have to define empty variable first and save something to the variable if try-catch doesn't catch any errors? I updated the example code for it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a common wrapper function, or install await-promise-wrapper:

As await exits, if error occurs there is no catch as we have in promise based implementation

**//wrapper.js**

```
export default function forActivity(promise){
   return promise
       .then( result => [null,result])
       .catch(err => [err])
}
```

**// yourFile.js**

```
import forActivity from wrapper.js
const [err, redditJSON] = await forActivity(rp(optForReddit));
if(err) console.log("error");
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are dead in ES7 and should no longer be used. To perform error handling with the new async await pattern you should wrap the call in a try/catch block.

It should look something like this:

```
try {
   let redditJSON = await rp(optForReddit);
   // do some cool stuff
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    // The contents of err should be what is thrown in the rp function
}
```

If you are using a library such as request-promise to perform this request the error should be thrown automatically and thrown up to this try/catch block.

However, remember you can always throw errors yourself as well, like so:

```
async myMethod() {
    throw new Error('something went wrong');
}
```

Then catch it like this:

```
try {
    await myMethod()
} catch (err) {
    // err = 'Something went wrong'
}
```

Comment: I'm just kind of wondering why people define errors using `throw new error` because you can just print error using `console.error("something went wrong")` in one line.

Comment: An error should always be an exceptional case. If the Error is not caught correctly, then it should crash your app. If an error is uncaught the program should not be allowed to continue. i.e. if I have the following code for example:

`const result = await rp(opts); const post = result.posts;`

If the rp method fails, it should throw an error and the next line should not be allowed to execute (there are no results because it has failed). If you used console.log here, the rp method would swallow the error and u will never know about it.

Comment: Further, the error object also has some special properties that can give you more information related to the error. For example err.stack will give you a printout of the call stack information, this can help you identify how the function was called that called the error.
Check out here for for info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save off the temporary variable as it will never have a value if you make it to the catch block.

In the simple version that Paul posted, if you hit the catch block, reddittJSON will be undefined, so you can always check that if you need to.

Now the cool thing with the latest promises and await is that you can set many processes going asynchronously and then sync them up later.

```
try {
    let promise1 = rp(longCall).promise();
    let promise2 = rp(longCall2).promise();

    let [response1, response2] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
// response1 and response2 will be undefined here if there was an error
```

Read here for more information.
http://javascriptrambling.blogspot.com/2017/04/to-promised-land-with-asyncawait-and.html

After programming java for over 20 years, I'm really excited with the great leaps javascript has made in the last few years.